# How to know what number should be input in From Min and From Max in Map Range Node?

Tags: geometry-nodes

This node Map Range takes a min and a max from incoming data, but as far as I know, GN has no nodes that can return the domain of the incoming data.
So how come one knows which number should be input there?
Or Does this node remap incoming data from 0 to 1 automatically so one never needs to know the bounds of the input data?

[image]

Comment: You can know the range of attribute values with the attribute statistic node. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/attribute/attribute_statistic.html

Comment: Oh, Thank you very much! I didn't know there is a node that can tell you the bounds of the data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, depending on what you plug into the *Value* input, you probably know in which range those values could be. Apart from that, it only remaps from 0 to 1 if you set it to this range. You can enter any range you want/need as *To Min* and *To Max* values.

And then there is the *Clamp* option. If it is enabled, every input value smaller than *From Min* will be set to *To Min* and values larger than *From Max* will be clamped to *To Max*.

If the *Clamp* option is disabled, input values outside of the *From Min* - *From Max* range will be extrapolated proportionally to the given output range.

For the *Linear Interpolation* (which is the only one the *Map Range* node in your screenshot is capable of, it seems you're using an older version) the output value is calculated by this formula:

$$Output=\textit{To Min}+\frac{To_{Range}}{From_{Range}}\cdot(Input-\textit{From Min})$$

with
$$To_{Range}=\textit{To Max}-\textit{To Min}$$ and $$From_{Range}=\textit{From Max}-\textit{From Min}$$

This is the general formula which will give the result for any input if the *Map Range* node is **not clamped**.

For a **clamped** *Map Range* node the result is diverted into three coditions, the input value either being lower than the *From Min* value, or being within the *From...* range or being higher than the *From Max* value. The result is then:

$$Output =
\begin{cases}
\textit{To Min}       & \! \text{if } Input < \textit{From Min}\\ \\
\textit{To Min}+\frac{To_{Range}}{From_{Range}}(Input-\textit{From Min})  & \! \text{if }\textit{From Min}\leq Input \leq\textit{From Max}\\ \\
\textit{To Max}       & \! \text{if } Input > \textit{From Max}
  \end{cases}
$$

The output values of a *Map Range* node set to convert a range of -1 to 1 into a range of 0 to 3 are shown in the follwoing diagram, comparing a clamped and unclamped node:

[image: map range node output]

So to conclude this excursion, depending on what kind of input you feed into the *Map Range* node, there can be ways to find an information about the *From Min* to *From Max* range. For example, if you plug a *Math* node in there calculating a *Sine* value, the range will always be -1 to 1. If you scale objects randomly and take the scale as input, the range will be the *Min/Max* values of the *Random Value* node.

And then it depends on what result you want to get: if you want to make sure the output value never exceeds the *To Min/To Max* range, then you should clamp the node. If you want to get values outside this range (maybe because you don't know the input range and don't want to cut off values), then you should not clamp the node.

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much for so kind reply. Now understand it much better!