# Need help converting a distance value to a decimal value between 0 and 1

Tags: drivers, masking

I have an object (a rollaway shutter panel) that I have set up with the Mask node and a linear gradient.

I have another object (the shutter handle) that I want to use to control the Mask threshold value by movement of the control object along the Z axis.

I added a driver to the Mask threshold value and set it to evaluate the controlling object's Z transform.

I have used the constraint Limit Distance on the controlling object. The constraint is on the Z axis from 0.394179m to 2.48006 and I have checked the "Affect Transform" box so that the reported value is also constrained.

I have tried to create an expression that will control the Mask threshold using the controller's Z transform property, but so far it has been a failure. It works... but with no precision.

Moving the controlling object on the Z controls the Mask threshold, but because there is no value match between the Z location and the Mask threshold value, the result is that the mask is always either ahead of or behind the movement of the controlling object.

If I am understanding my problem correctly, I need to make an expression to convert the distance the controlling object travels (roughly 2.08592) to values between 0 and 1 so that the Mask threshold value is correct.

Can someone suggest an expression that will convert distance travelled to decimal values between 0 and 1, where the value starts at 0 and ends at 1?

I'm certain there is a mathematical way to accomplish this, but math just isn't one of my strengths.

Thank you in advance for any assistance!

Comment: A visual support of what this looks like and the settings in nodes, modifiers or constraints  would really help understanding what is going on there. And for the values, 0.39... and 2.48..., are they fixed? So you basically just need the mathematic formula of a _Map Range_ node where you would set 0.39 and 2.48 as the "From" values and map them to 0 and 1 as "To" values?

Comment: I wish I could provide a visual, but unfortunately in this instance, I can't. However, to answer your second question, the two values are fixed; they are the range of travel of the control object on the Z axis and they are locked. But rather than a node (unless that can be pushed to an expression) I need an expression (forumula) in the drivers panel to do the conversion.

Comment: Well, the formula for the linear mapping of one range of values to another range of values you can find here: [Map Range mathematics](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/293473/how-to-know-what-number-should-be-input-in-from-min-and-from-max-in-map-range-no/293490#293490), so I guess in a driver editor where you have an expression with the default variable $var$ as the driver input (the Z value), the expression would probably look like that: $$0+\frac{1}{2.48-0.39}\cdot (var - 0.39) = \frac{ (var - 0.39)}{2.09}$$